# ng-style or style in ion-nav-view not getting value from controller

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-style

I am making a hbrid app using ionic and have encountered the following problem. I have tried both

```
<ion-nav-view ng-style="winHeight"></ion-nav-view>
```

and

```
<ion-nav-view style="{{winHeight}}"></ion-nav-view>
```

but none of thoes gets value from my controller

```
if (!angular.isArray(data)) {
    $scope.winHeight = 'height: ' + ($window.innerHeight - 40) + 'px !important';
} else {
    $scope.winHeight = 'height: ' + ($window.innerHeight) + 'px !important';
}

console.log($scope.winHeight);
```

console.log give me the correct text, but when I load and inspect the element, everything I see is

```
<ion-nav-view ng-style="winHeight" class="view-container" nav-view-transition="ios" nav-view-direction="none" nav-swipe="">
```

or

```
<ion-nav-view style="{{winHeight}}" class="view-container" nav-view-transition="ios" nav-view-direction="none" nav-swipe="">
```

When I instead write

```
<ion-nav-view style="height:528px !important;"></ion-nav-view>
```

it works like I want, but then it's not dynamic. Anyone know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `ng-style` should be JSON & just pass height value from `winHeight` variable

```
<ion-nav-view ng-style="{height: winHeight}"></ion-nav-view>
```

**Code**

```
if (!angular.isArray(data)) {
    $scope.winHeight = ($window.innerHeight - 40) + ' px !important';
} else {
    $scope.winHeight =($window.innerHeight) + 'px !important';
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this did not work. Inspecting the element gives me `<ion-nav-view ng-style="{height: winHeight}" class="view-container" nav-view-transition="ios" nav-view-direction="none" nav-swipe="">`